# Page Specific Widgets with TypePad - Avoiding Sitewides

Tags: textbox, widget, typepad

I would love to place a text widget in my typepad blog that only appeared on the homepage, and not on the rest of the site. Thanks for your help!

Best,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

From your dashboard click on 'design', click on 'templates' and then choose 'date based archive' in there put in a line to add in the module containing your widget in the correct section eg:

```
<$MTWeblogIncludeModule module="my-widget"$>
```

If you using a standard three column layout then you'll find something like, sounds like somewhere in beta-inner will work:

```
<$MTWeblogIncludeModule module="body-header"$>
<div id="container">
    <div id="container-inner" class="pkg">
        <$MTWeblogIncludeModule module="container-header"$>
        <$MTInclude module="banner"$>
        <div id="pagebody">
            <div id="pagebody-inner" class="pkg">
                <div id="beta">
                    <div id="beta-inner" class="pkg">
```